# IIS IP restrictions - Deny and Allow Precedence

Tags: iis-7

Out of necessity (my hosting provider), I have to allow a range of IP addresses. Using IIS 7.5 IP Address and Domain Resrictions feature, I set up the deny all feature and then added my Allow entry with an appropriate ip address and subnet mask e.g. 192.168.106.1 and 255.255.255.0 so that the range allowed was 192.168.106.1 to 192.168.106.254. Then I wanted to deny one specific ip address within this range so I added a deny entry for 192.168.106.147. However, testing showed that I could still access my site using the .147 address. I thought that Deny entries might overrule Allow entries (for safety) but it would appear that Allow entries have precedence. Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try changing the order? i.e., give deny rule before accept rule.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and report back.

Comment: I deleted both the Allow and the Deny entries, then added the Deny entry first and then the Allow entry. And this worked. However, the normal IIS view showed the Allow entry first and then the Deny entry - its not until you click the View Ordered List (on the right-hand side) that you see the actual physical order and you get access to the 'Move Up' and 'Move Down' functions. So you don't need to delete any of your entries.